# How to convert a string value contains List to proper List with out string " " in xslt 3.0

Tags: xml, xslt

This contains in my xsl

```
<items> 
   <xsl:value-of select="$getPickingItemsResponse/items" />
</items>
```

Its coming as
 "[{toID=ABCD, qty=2, name=525031, pkg=EA1, altNumber=alt52503}, {toID=EFGH, qty=2, name=525032, pkg=EA2, altNumber=alt525032}, {toID=IJKL, qty=2, name=525033, pkg=EA3, altNumber=alt525033}]"

so the JSON i am getting is,

```
"items": "[{toID=ABCD, qty=2, name=525031, pkg=EA1, altNumber=alt52503}, {toID=EFGH, qty=2, name=525032, pkg=EA2, altNumber=alt525032}, {toID=IJKL, qty=2, name=525033, pkg=EA3, altNumber=alt525033}]",
```

What I want is

[{toID=ABCD, qty=2, name=525031, pkg=EA1, altNumber=alt52503}, {toID=EFGH, qty=2, name=525032, pkg=EA2, altNumber=alt525032}, {toID=IJKL, qty=2, name=525033, pkg=EA3, altNumber=alt525033}]

So that in the JSON

```
 "items": [{toID=ABCD, qty=2, name=525031, pkg=EA1, altNumber=alt52503}, {toID=EFGH, qty=2, name=525032, pkg=EA2, altNumber=alt525032}, {toID=IJKL, qty=2, name=525033, pkg=EA3, altNumber=alt525033}]
```

So that I can traverse to the JSON Array.

Comment: JSON requires double quotes as delimiters around the property names of objects so I am afraid I don't see any JSON in there.

Comment: Also in JSON each property name is separated by a colon `:` from its value, not by the `=` symbol.

Comment: Show us your source document: in particular, what is in `$getPickingItemsResponse/items`?